# Cannot summarise variables by group in dplyr when passing frames as a function

Tags: r, dplyr

I am hopeing to use dplyr to pass multimple data frames to a function and then return a data frame with the summarised variables.  I am able to do this no problem at the aggregate level, but when I try to group by a factor the function returns the same values for the overall aggregate.  Here is an example I have that is working fine:

```
compCalc <- function(frame,segment) {
     newFrame <- frame %>% 
     summarise(seg = segment,
          FTEs = sum(FTEs),
          total_TCC = sum(frame$totalCompensationCost),
          TCC_per_fte = sum(frame$totalCompensationCost)/sum(frame$FTEs),
          TCC_per_hour = sum(frame$totalCompensationCost)/sum(frame$hours),
          total_wages = sum(frame$totalWages))
return(newFrame)
}
```

I then call the function like so:

```
nuSectorOverall <- compCalc(dfEx, "allNonUnion")
```

and I get nice output like this:

```
Overall
seg         FTEs     total_TCC    TCC_per_fte  TCC_per_hour total_wages 
allNonUnion 3980.559 185865849     46693.4     24.09153      171344280
```

Now when I introduce a group_by clause into the mix like so:

```
compCalcEmp <- function(frame,segment) {
    newFrame <- frame %>% 
        group_by(employeeGroup) %>%
            summarise(seg = segment,
                FTEs = sum(FTEs),
                total_TCC = sum(frame$totalCompensationCost),
                TCC_per_fte = sum(frame$totalCompensationCost)/sum(frame$FTEs),
                TCC_per_hour = sum(frame$totalCompensationCost)/sum(frame$hours),
                total_wages = sum(frame$totalWages))
          return(newEmpFrame)
  }
```

I run into the following problem:

```
employeeGroup     seg      FTEs total_TCC TCC_per_fte TCC_per_hour     total_wages total_wages_per_fte
              <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>           <dbl>               <dbl>
1       Bargaining Unit overall  139.2841 185865849     46693.4     24.09153       171344280            43045.28
2 Management & Excluded overall  402.0311 185865849     46693.4     24.09153   171344280            43045.28
3             Non-Union overall 3439.2438 185865849     46693.4     24.09153   171344280            43045.28
```

As you can see it is calculating the same values for each grouped variable with the exception of FTEs!

I looked long and hard to see if there was a similar question to this one and I apologize if I did not find it.  any help would be very much appreciated!

All best,

r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use `frame$` to refer to columns of `frame` inside the `dplyr` pipe. Try this instead:

```
compCalcEmp <- function(frame,segment) {
    newFrame <- frame %>% 
        group_by(employeeGroup) %>%
            summarise(seg = segment,
                FTEs = sum(FTEs),
                total_TCC = sum(totalCompensationCost),
                TCC_per_fte = sum(totalCompensationCost)/sum(FTEs),
                TCC_per_hour = sum(totalCompensationCost)/sum(hours),
                total_wages = sum(totalWages))
   return(newFrame)
}
```

It worked before without the `group_by` because in that case you are summarizing with respect to the whole `frame` and not by subset groups.

Comment: That worked!  Thank you so much for takign the time to help me!  I really appreciate it!